# JQuery - Fadein an ajaxForm() page call

Tags: jquery

I have this script that opens a new page inside a span:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
            $('#botao').click( function() {
                $('#pesquisar').ajaxForm({
                    type: 'POST', 
                    target: '#resultado'
                });
            });
        });
```

I want the new page to fadein, i have tried putting fadein() around with no luck. How do i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the [`beforeSubmit` and `success`](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#ajaxForm) callbacks should get there. Something like this:

```
$('#pesquisar').ajaxForm({
    type: 'POST', 
    target: '#resultado',
    beforeSubmit: function() { $('#resultado').css('display', 'none'); },
    success: function() { $('#resultado').fadeIn(); }
});
```

The `beforeSubmit` callback is called right before the form is submitted and hides `#resultado` in preparation for the fadeIn. Then `ajaxForm` should put the response in `#resultado` and call the `success` callback; the success callback does the `fadeIn`.

I don't have a handy `ajaxForm` setup so I can't test this but I'm pretty sure that the above will work.

Comment: I tried here but it didnt work, the page doesnt fade, it just pops in =/

Comment: @onildo: What happens if you `fadeIn(1000)` to slow it down? You could also check the content of `#resultado` in the success handler to make sure I have the callback call order right but hidding "submit 5" on [this example](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#ajaxForm) indicates that it should work.

Comment: i was using #resultado as a span, when i changed it to div and it worked just fine, thank you

Comment: @onildo: Cool, I assumed that `#resultado` was a block element, I should know better than to make assumptions :)

Comment: This page is a search page, and the form is the result. I want to show  the edit page using the same method but, it would just be one page inside another page inside another page, is there any way to make the new page to 'overwrite' the old one?

Comment: @onildo: I'm not sure what structure you're dealing with but couldn't you just use some target higher up the DOM than `#resultado`?

Comment: If i target the div where the search page is in, it will add the next page's content or overwrite the search page and put the new one?

Comment: @onildo: I think so, try it and see what happens. Careful with your references to `#resultado` though, it might not exist depending on your HTML structure.

Comment: I was trying to do the same process like, opening a new page over the current one without reload, but with a link, not a form. Tried messing around with this code but it didnt work, is there any way of doing that?

Comment: @onildo: Something like [`$('#thing').load(url)`](http://api.jquery.com/load) perhaps?